# Change Cpanel New Domain File Root Default

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have been trying to create a new domain in my cpanel acocunt.

How can I remove the /public_html/as the default root?

[image: Print Cpanel New Domain]

Like this?

[image: Cpanel New Domain]

I looked everywhere and couldn't find it.

I have WHM root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access, log in to  WHM >> Tweak Settings and make sure that "Restrict document roots to public_html" is set to "Off".

This should solve your issue.